# Declaring functions and variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory, memory-management

I'm building a large React application that involves processing lots of data, formatting it and outputting to tables. Occasionally these functions are variables (e.g const x = () => etc.)

I'm storing the functions that do this formatting in Typescript files which I import into my React components.

To give an example, I might write a table formatting function like this:

```
export const buildMainData = (data: any) => {
  do stuff
}
```

I'm placing it inside a file, called functions.ts (for example).

I then have a React component which makes use of the function.

My question is - is this a bad idea? Am I creating loads of functions that are polluting the memory heap? I'm using create-react-app so I'm not sure if Webpack is doing some magic behind the scenes to prevent global variables, or whether everything I write should be placed inside of React components.

It would be great if anyone with more experience / knowledge in this area could help out. If I'm also completely getting the wrong end of the stick that would also be helpful to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The variables and functions you're exporting aren't *globals*, they're exports from the module in which you define them. They're used via import. If you have some that aren't used, modern bundlers like Webpack and Rollup can *tree-shake* the bundle they create, leaving unused functions out (if there are any). More about tree-shaking [in Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and [in Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#tree-shaking).

It's true that top-level declarations in classic scripts are globals, but top-level declarations in modules are scoped to the module (kind of like the module were a function and you were declaring things inside it), and then possibly exported from it.